# WPF Chatbox control

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, wpf-controls, chat

currently I'm working on a chat client and changed my client from windows forms (as forms is shitty) to WPF. I'm not really sure which control could be used to realize a chatbox. I could take a TextBox but this will not display the complete content when it's full. I also tried to use a ListBox but when I try to add items they are not displayed. I used this code to add content to it:

```
internal void AddMessage(string message)
{
    listBox_messages.Items.Add(message);
    listBox_messages.Items.Refresh();
}
```

Does anybody knows which control would be the best for this purpose?

Thanks for your help!

Edit: 
I implemented a TextBox for this and disabled it. But the text I'm appending by this method is not shown.
My class:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace Chat_Client
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// MainWindow constructor
        /// </summary>
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            textBox_messages.AppendText("Test" + "\n");
            textBox_messages.AppendText("Test" + "\n");
            textBox_messages.AppendText("Test" + "\n");

            Closing += OnWindowClosing;
        }

        private void OnWindowClosing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            Program.Shutdown();
        }

        private void button_connect_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(Program.Connected)
            {
                Program.Disconnect();
            }
            else
            {
                Program.Connect();
            }            
        }

        private void button_sendMessage_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        internal void AddMessage(string message)
        {
            textBox_messages.AppendText(message + "\n");
        }
    }
}
```

The test strings are shown but the text added by the method AddMessage is not. I can verify that the method is called, I just checked it with a breakpoint inside this method. Anybody has a clue how this could happen?

Comment: The prefered WPF way is to use data binding(MVVM) rather than manipulating the UI directly. You can have ListBox with ControlTemplate to display messages. this [example](http://wblum.org/listbind/net3/index.html) is similar to what you are trying to do.

Comment: You really shouldn't to all that stuff in the code behind. Instead, use view-models and connect views and view-models using bindings and commands.

Comment: Well I'm new to WPF at all and a bit overwhelmed with such models. I just want a stupid and primitve form with WPF and not with Forms.

Comment: You probably have a threading problem. I have updated my answer regarding that.

Comment: As you accepted an answer, can you explain, how you solved your problem?

Comment: I mixed the marked solution with your answer especially regarding MVVM. I can't accept both answers although both are right and are the solution. I fixed my old problem which was threading related with your edited answer and mixed it up with the suggestion @androonoise made. However I now started a clean project using the MVVM model and I'm fighting threw some tutorials. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Good decision. MVVM is worth the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*In response to your edit: where are you calling AddMessage() from? I tried your code and just called AddMessage("foo"); from the button click event and worked fine.

For a chat box, I would use a TextBox to write the chat messages, and wrap it with a ScrollViewer for scrolling. After using AppendText() on the TextBox to write the message, you can then call ScrollToEnd() to scroll to the bottom of the TextBox.

In the XAML:

`<ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_OnScrollChanged">
            <TextBox x:Name="ChatBox"/>
</ScrollViewer>`

In the code behind:

```
    private void WriteToChat(string message)
    {
        ChatBox.AppendText(message);
        ChatBox.ScrollToEnd();
    }

    private bool _autoScroll = true;
    private void ScrollViewer_OnScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ExtentHeightChange == 0)
        {
            _autoScroll = ScrollViewer.VerticalOffset == ScrollViewer.ScrollableHeight;
        }

        if (_autoScroll && e.ExtentHeightChange != 0)
        {
            ScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(ScrollViewer.ExtentHeight);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why are you adding a underscore to the variable? I have seen this already a couple of times but I never understood when this should be done.

Comment: Adding an underscore is a common convention that helps to distinguish class fields from local variables.

Comment: Responding to your edit: I'm calling the AddMessage method from the static class Program handling the TcpConnection and other things. When calling this method in the same class I have no problem but if it's called from outer it's not working.

Comment: Have you tried changing your AddMessage method to public? Maybe it's an issue with the internal keyword?

Comment: I just tried it with public but this doesn't helped. I added a Invoker to make the async write possible but it seems to me that my whole form is not updating at all. Getting the text of the username field is always empty when getting it from a static context. Is it not allowed to access these elements from a static context?

Comment: However, I will contact a friend of mine for help as he has more access to the source. Still huge thanks for the reply! It helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

If the Program class calls AddMessage(string) from within another thread than the UI thread, you have to use a Dispatcher in order to update the UI.

```cs
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
{
    mainWindow.AddMessage(message);
}));
```

---

[MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) is the way to go when using WPF.

1. Add your messages to an [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) in your ViewModel class (ChatViewModel.cs):

```cs
public class ChatViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Messages { get; } = new ObservableCollection<string>();

    internal void AddMessage(string message)
    {
        Messages.Add(message);
    }
}
```

2. Set this ViewModel as the DataContext of your View (ChatView.xaml)

```cs
public ChatView : UserControl
{
    public ChatView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ChatViewModel();
    }
}
```

3. In the XAML-Code bind the ObservableCollection to the [ItemsSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource(v=vs.110).aspx) property of your [ListBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Messages}") />
```

When you add a message to the Messages collection it should appear inside the ListBox. This is not a complete example, but it should guide you into the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a TextBox and set the VerticalAlignment to Stretch in your Xaml file.

< TextBox x:Name="textbox" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">